# Aggregate results from multiple Mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are several models that are considerably different and belong to different collections, yet they have common fields that will be used when query results are aggregated together.

```
const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  promoteAtMainPage: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  timestamp: Date,
  active: Boolean,
  / * the rest are different */
});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  promoteAtMainPage: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  timestamp: Date,
  active: Boolean,
  / * the rest are different */
});
```

Only common fields (`title`, `body`, `timestamp`) are used from the result.

Additionally, if `promoteAtMainPage` is missing in document, this should be treated differently in these models (it defaults to `true` in one case and `false` in another).

Currently this is done with result processing:

```
let blogPosts = await BlogPost.aggregate([{ $match { active: true } }, { $sort: { timestamp: -1} }, { $limit: 100 } }]);

for (let blogPost of blogPosts)
  blogPost.promoteAtMainPage = ('promoteAtMainPage' in blogPost)
    ? blogPost.promoteAtMainPage
    : false;

let articles = await Article.aggregate([{ $match { active: true } }, { $sort: { timestamp: -1} }, { $limit: 100 } }]);

for (let article of articles)
  article .promoteAtMainPage = ('promoteAtMainPage' in article )
    ? article .promoteAtMainPage
    : true;

let mainPagePosts = [...blogPosts, ...articles]
  .filter(post => post.promoteAtMainPage)
  .sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
  .slice(0, 100);
```

This results in requesting 200 documents instead of 100 and doing extra `sort`.

Is this possible in this case to aggregate the results from different collections by means of Mongoose or Mongodb only?

Can the case with missing `promoteAtMainPage` field be handled by Mongodb as well, or the only reasonable way to handle this is to apply a migration to all existing documents and add default `promoteAtMainPage` value?

Comment: Your problem is that these are in two collections. You solve it by putting them in one collection. MongoDB has no schema so you can do that. You can apply a schema for each type using [discriminators.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html). No such thing as a "union query" with MongoDB. The MongoDB solution to such is to "put in in the same collection" instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I considered this as an option, but these models are very different, so these few fields are only things that they have in common. There was no reason to join them with discriminators until this moment. So discriminators and postprocessing are the only possibilities here, aren't they?

Comment: Which is why you need to read it, because I'm too tired now to write out a lengthy answer explaining all of that. The simple fact is mentioned. You cannot "join" collections in that way. So put the data in **one collecton**.

Comment: I appreciate your help in Mongo topics, but this tirade was uncalled-for. I'm aware of how things are done in Mongo, and I'm aware of the fact that storing all documents in same collection would help to avoid this problem (and probably would add other ones I'm not aware of yet).. This doesn't rule out the possibility that there can be Mongo(ose) features I don't know about that could help here. Right now I'm evaluating `$out` for that but still not sure if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at $mergeObjects from the MongoDB documentation. It allows you to combine fields from multiple collections and return a new temporary collection with documents combined from the original collections.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/

You might be able to use that to combine your BlogPost and Article collections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it.